# Firebase phone authentication SendVerificationCodeRequest - MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have an android application that use the firebase authentication.
It's been working fine for around 6 months.

Today, we got a report where 2 user unable to do the phone verification.
Here is the error log:

[image: Here is the error log]

I tried to reproduced the error and register using a new number, but it works fine.

I also check that there is no AppVerificationDisabledForTesting in the current project configuration.

Is there any idea how to reproduced this and why this is happening?
Its strange because it only happen to 2 user.